# React-Auth0? Working! React-Redux-Auth0? I am losing my mind :/

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, auth0

This is a really long post, but I really need some help :/

I will be eternally grateful if someone would be able to help.

I have managed to get Auth0 working for an application i am working on with just react. It is an Overwatch SR tracker, and is essentially just a spreadsheet so I wasn't too concerned with protecting backend routes when I make them. There isn't any private information there.

My application state/props network became too complicated to manage, and through the process of implementing redux I simply cannot get it to work. I've been at it for three days, and I'm running out of ideas. Do I need Thunk with my current Auth setup to do this? I would imagine it is async since it needs to go get something that isnt there.

Granted I am a junior Dev, and dont have much experience with authentication. Can someone take a look at my working react application and guide me in the direction of what i may need to do to set it up with redux? I do have an understanding of redux flow, so if the proper method to do this was explained to me i feel i might get it.

here is some code:

my Auth.js file :

```
/*eslint no-restricted-globals: 0 */
import auth0 from "auth0-js";
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

const LOGIN_SUCCESS_PAGE = '/menu';
const LOGIN_FAILURE_PAGE = '/';

export default class Auth {
  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: "redacted.auth0.com",
    clientID: "redacted",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
    audience: "https://redacted.auth0.com/userinfo",
    responseType: "token id_token",
    scope: "openid profile"
  });

  constructor() {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  login() {
    this.auth0.authorize();
  }

  handleAuthentication() {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResults) => {
        if (authResults && authResuslts.accessToken && authResults.idToken) {
            let expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResults.expiresIn) * 1000 + new Date().getTime());
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", authResults.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem("id_token", authResults.idToken);
            localStorage.setItem("expires_at", expiresAt);
            location.hash = "";
            location.pathname = LOGIN_SUCCESS_PAGE;
        } else if (err) {
            location.pathname = LOGIN_FAILURE_PAGE;
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    let expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
    return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
  }
  logout() {
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
      localStorage.removeItem("id_token");
      localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
      location.pathname = LOGIN_FAILURE_PAGE;
  }

  getProfile() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("id_token")) {
        console.log(jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem("id_token")))
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("id_token"));
        return jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem("id_token"));
    } else {
        return {
          name: 'Anon',
          nickname: 'Anon',
          picture: 'placeholder',
          uid: null,
        }
    }
  }
}
```

my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Auth from './Auth';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const auth = new Auth();

let state = {};
window.setState = (changes) => {
    state = Object.assign({}, state, changes)
    ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App {...state} />
        </BrowserRouter>,
        document.getElementById('root'));
}

/* eslint no-restricted-globals: 0*/

let getUserProfile = auth.getProfile();

let initialState = {
    owSrTrackInfo: {
        infoSaved: false,
        accounts: [],
    },
    user: getUserProfile,
    location: location.pathname.replace(/^\/?|\/$/g, ""),
    auth,
}

window.setState(initialState);

registerServiceWorker();
```

my App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Main from "./Components/Main/Main";
import Menu from "./Pages/Menu/Menu";
import NotFound from "./Components/NotFound/NotFound";
import Callback from './Components/Callback/Callback';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let mainComponent = "";
    switch (this.props.location) {
      case "":
        mainComponent = <Main {...this.props} />;
        break;
      case "callback":
        mainComponent = <Callback />
        break;
      case "menu":
        mainComponent = this.props.auth.isAuthenticated() ? < Menu {...this.props} /> : <NotFound />;
        break;
      default:
        mainComponent = <NotFound />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="app">

        <Header {...this.props} />
        {mainComponent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my Callback.js component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Auth from '../../Auth'

export default class Callback extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const auth = new Auth();
        auth.handleAuthentication();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <p className="loading">Loading.....</p>
        )
    }
}
```

My current MAIN.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.auth.getProfile())
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <div className='container--logged-out'>
          <h1 className="heading u-margin-bottom-small">welcome to redacteds' overwatch sr tracker</h1>
            <p>Hello there {this.props.user.nickname}! Sign in single click or email via Auth0 so we can save your results, and make the app usable by more than one person. I intend for more than one person to use this, so just to launch it and so the app knows your spreadsheet from someone elses I'll tie each user to their own UID. Feel free to come back, log in, and get your spreadsheet for the season back anytime.</p>
          </div>
          <a href="/menu">Go to the app menu!</a>
          <button onClick={() =>this.props.auth.getProfile()}>asdgkljsdngk</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

my current HEADER.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header className="header">
                <h1 className='header__text'>SR TRACKER</h1>
                {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated() ?
                    <button className='btn btn--logout' onClick={() => this.props.auth.logout()}>Logout</button>
                    :
                    <button className='btn btn--login' onClick={() => this.props.auth.login()}>Login or Sign Up</button>}
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

I simply want to map this authentication to a redux store instead to be consitent with the rest of my app (when redux is implemented) I have blown it away and started over multiple times, but a rough idea of what my redux flow might look like is like this template i use and have successfully implemented several times:

redux store:

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const middleware = [
    createLogger({
      collapsed: false,
      duration: true,
      diff: true,
    }),
    thunk,
  ];

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : format => format, // add support for Redux dev tools),
    ),
  );

  return store;
}
```

actionTypes.js in actions folder:

```
const actions = {
  GET_FRIENDS: 'GET_FRIENDS',
  REMOVE_FRIEND: 'REMOVE_FRIEND',

  GET_MOVIES: 'GET_MOVIES',
  GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS: 'GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS',
  GET_MOVIES_FAILURE: 'GET_MOVIES_FAILURE',

  DEVIN_FUN: 'DEVIN_FUN',
};

export default actions;
```

Sample actions page:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const getMoviesSuccess = data => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS,
    data,
  };
};

export const getMoviesFailure = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.GET_MOVIES_FAILURE,
  };
};

export const devinIsHavingFun = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.DEVIN_FUN,
  };
};

export const retrieveMovies = () => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    const API_KEY = 'trilogy';

    dispatch(devinIsHavingFun());

    axios
      .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com?apikey=${API_KEY}&s=frozen`)
      .then(data => {
        dispatch(getMoviesSuccess(data.data.Search));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch(getMoviesFailure());
      });
  };
};
```

in the reducers folder wed have some files like initialState.js and root reducer that look like this respectively:

initialState.js:

```
export default {
  friends: [],
  movies: [],
};
```

rootReducer.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import friends from './friendReducer';
import movies from './movieReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  friends,
  movies,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and a sample reducer:

```
import actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function movieReducer(state = initialState.movies, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_MOVIES_SUCCESS: {
      return action.data;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

I just dont know what to do. Do i need to use thunk? am I overthinking this? I'm pulling my hair out.

I also do connect my components  in this fashion when redux is implemented :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as friendActionCreators from './actions/friendActions';
import * as movieActionCreators from './actions/movieActions';

....................
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    myFriends: state.friends,
    movies: state.movies,
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    friendActions: bindActionCreators(friendActionCreators, dispatch),
    movieActions: bindActionCreators(movieActionCreators, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Please let me know if anyone can point me in the right direction. thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Indeed it's a long question. I suggest that you try and condense it to something smaller. You could also try to use something like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to create working/not working samples. IMHO it would make it easier for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll set that up tomorrow!